# AJAX pass data to PHP

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I've been searching this forum, but I had no good result. I have this HTML:

```
<form method="post" id="postform">
          <input type="text" name="message" id="message" placeholder='Say "Hello!"' class="mymessage" maxlength="255"/>
          <br />
         <input id="submit" type="button" value="Send"/>
        </form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
include ('connect.php');
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['message'])){
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO messages VALUES ('','".$_POST['message']."','".$_SESSION['user']."')");
}
?>
```

And jQuery:

```
$('#submit').click(
function(){
    var message = $('#message').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: post.php,
        type:'POST',
        data: {"message":message}   
        });
    });
```

I need to pass #message content to PHP without refreshig the page. This is what I've made, but it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

Check your syntax:

1. Wrap `url` with quotes `'`
2. Remove single quotes around `'message'` variable

   ```
   $.ajax({
       url:  'post.php',
       type: 'POST',
       data: {message : message}   
   }).done(function( msg ) {
       alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
   });
   ```

See the first example of [**$.ajax()**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) at the bottom of its documentation page.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to pass #message content to PHP without refreshig the page.

Handle form submit instead:

```
$("#postform").submit(function(){
    var message = $('#message').val();
    $.ajax({
       url: 'post.php',
       type:'POST',
       data: {message:message}   
    }).done(function( data) { 
        // handle response from the server in case of success.
    });

   return false; //to prevent submitting and refreshing the page.
});
```